# Toggle Skype notification status

Tags: shell-script, skype

Being notified whether a contact appears online/offline or not can be changed via the *Skype Options* or via the `~/.skype/your_skype_id/config.xml`. In this file, depending on what you chose, on can find the following lines:

```
<Notify>
  <Chat>0</Chat>
  <Offline>1</Offline>
  <Online>1</Online>
</Notify>
```

where `<Offline>n</Offline>` (resp. `<Online>n</Online>`) corresponds to the *"Contact came offline"* (resp. *"Contact came online"*) option and where `n` obviously states whether it's on or not.

Thus my question is the following: *Can one toggle the notifications on/off automatically?*

It's important to note that `Offline` and `Online` appear only once on the `XML` file.

So far all I can do is:

```
sed -i config.xml -e '197s!<Online>1</Online>!<Online>0</Online>!'
```

where `197` is the line number (which is case dependant, so it's pretty bad), and where I don't check the existing status of the notification, I only turn it off.

---

In short, what I would like to do is to change `0` to `1` (or `1` to `0`) automatically to both lines.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a job for a bash/shell script.

What I would is create a simple if statement using grep to search the file for 1 or 0 and then replace them using the command you have. Say:

```
if grep -q "<Online>1</Online>" "config.xml"; then
        echo "Statement Returned True, Will now execute"
        sed -i config.xml -e '197s!<Online>1</Online>!<Online>0</Online>!'

elif grep -q "<Online>0</Online>" "config.xml"; then
        echo "Statement Returned True, Will now execute"
        sed -i config.xml -e '197s!<Online>0</Online>!<Online>1</Online>!'
fi

if grep -q "<Offline>1</Offline>" "config.xml"; then
        echo "Statement Returned True, Will now execute"
        sed -i config.xml -e '197s!<Online>1</Online>!<Online>0</Online>!'

elif grep -q "<Offline>0</Offline>" "config.xml"; then
        echo "Statement Returned True, Will now execute"
        sed -i config.xml -e '197s!<Online>0</Online>!<Online>1</Online>!'
fi
```

And put that in a run.sh or something.

Comment: I'm afraid that the problem here is that the line (`197`) can change from one file to an other.

Comment: Grep should still be able to return a line number that it found the information on, I think that taking that line number and placing back into the 'sed' function should work.